# Same Java code to print triangle using asterisk showing different results

Tags: java

The following codeparts are exactly the same, however, it prints a different result and I am unable to understand why.

```
        //First Part
        final int MAX_ROWS = 10;        
        for (int row = 1; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++) 
        {
            for (int star = 1; star <= row; star++) 
                System.out.println("*");

            System.out.println();
        }
        
        System.out.println();
        
        //Second Part
        for (int row = 1; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++)
        {
            for (int star = 1; star <= row; star++)
                System.out.print ("*");
    
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: it's not the same. second to last print statement is different

Comment: Firstly, it's not the same (print is different from println). Secondly, is it intentional that the body of some of your for loops are not surrounded by brackets? Thirdly, I recommend formatting it in a more readable way to be able to find these types of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using print() in the second part of your code you should insert \n to wrap text, Because println() will do it by default.

Your code to work should be like :

```
    final int MAX_ROWS = 10;
    for (int row = 1; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++){
        for (int star = 1; star <= row; star++) {
            System.out.println("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println();

    for (int row = 1; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++){
        for (int star = 1; star <= row; star++) {
            System.out.print("*\n");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Or like this:

```
    final int MAX_ROWS = 10;
    for (int row = 1; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++) {
        for (int star = 1; star <= row; star++) {
            System.out.println("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println();

    for (int row = 1; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++) {
        for (int star = 1; star <= row; star++) {
            System.out.println("*");
        }
         System.out.println();
    }
```